# Installing software in Ansible / AWX on Windows using ansible.windows.win_package and when criteria

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying install Visual C++ on windows using ansible / awx.  I need to put a check in to confirm the version is lower before running.  I use ansible.windows.win_reg_stat to get the bld.raw_value from registry.  This is a 5 digit integer of the version number.  Microsoft frequently releases visual c++ runtimes and vmtools used 32bit and 64bit runtime.  However, during this deployment or release, Microsoft can release a newer runtime with a higher version number.  I cannot use the software guid because a newer version would have a different guid.  The code works win_package works when the 'when' is removed.

.

```
name:get reg value
ansible.windows.win_reg_stat:
  path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86
  name: Bld
register: Bld_x86

name: run visual c++
ansible.windows.win_package:
  path: "C:\\temp\\vcredist_x86.exe"
  state: present
  arguments:
    - /q
    - /norestart
 when: (Bld_x86.raw_value | int) < 32532
```

I am looking to either fix the 'when' criteria or find another way to perform an 'if'/'when' check for the win_package command

Comment: This is really easy to do on Linux system which has a package facts module which will return version numbers.  Are you looking for a way to compare the version? This is what I usually use to do that: `when: vastool.version is version('5.1.0.15600', '<')`. In this instance I am checking if the version of the software is less than 5.1.0.15600.